# How can I sync my contacts and calendars from Linux to and from an iPhone without using Google?

Tags: linux, sync, iphone, calendar, contacts

I recently moved from Mac to Linux (Fedora 25, to be exact). Everything works really well, but I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to sync my contacts and calendars.

I still use an iPhone, but there's no Linux version of iCloud. I don't want to put everything in Google because of security and trust concerns. What services exist to fill this void?

Comment: What are the security and trust concerns you have with Google, but not with Apple?

Comment: Apple's primary business model is selling hardware. Google's primary business model is selling ads and your personal information. It's not that Apple provokes no concerns, but Google's are an order of magnitude bigger.